# What does 'discourse vector' mean in word/sentence embedding?

Tags: nlp, words, embedding

While I read the paper below, I got a question what the discourse vector is. and how this vector is made up.

- S.Arora (TACL 2016): A Latent variable model approach to PMI-based Word Embeddings
- S.Arora (ICLR 2017): A simple but tough-to-beat baseline for sentence embeddings

In this paper, it says,
"discourse vector represents what is being talked about"

But it is not clear to me.

In summary, my question is

1. what the discourse vector means; is it topic or context or something else?
2. Then if so, how do we create this vector?
3. how this vector learn? or is it fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the paragraph from the paper "Linear Algebraic Structure of Word Senses, with Applications to Polysemy" by Sanjeev Arora.

*It posits that at every point in the corpus there is a **micro-topic (“what is being talked about”) called discourse** that is drawn
from the continuum of unit vectors in ℜ<sup>d</sup>. The parameters of the model include a vector V<sub>w</sub> ∈ ℜ<sup>d</sup> for each word w. Each discourse 'c' defines a distribution over words Pr[w | c] ∝ exp(c · V<sub>w</sub>). The model assumes that the corpus is generated by the slow geometric random walk of c over the unit sphere in ℜ<sup>d</sup>: when the walk is at c, a few words are emitted by i.i.d. samples from the distribution (2), which, due to its log-linear form, strongly favors words close to c in cosine similarity.*

Each discourse is topic. Authors have fixed the topics to 2000 in the paper.

One way to fix the discourse vector could be the simple average of the neighbouring word vectors as an estimate (MLE).
This naive sentence embedding can be improved by taking a weighted combination (often tf-idf) of adjacent words.

Paper uses weighted average of word embedding in the window, with smaller weights for more frequent words (reminiscent of tf-idf) called SIF embedding for better estimate of the discourse.